Problem with reaching the max ICOsupply during minting in ICO
I'm encountering an issue with my ICO token minting logic. Specifically, I have a problem where the token's totalSupply doesn't seem to reach its maximum limit (ICO_SUPPLY) as expected during the minting process.
function _icoBuy(uint256 wethAmount) internal returns (uint256 tokenAmount) {
    uint256 remainingSupply = token.ICO_SUPPLY() - erc20token.totalSupply();
    tokenAmount = wethAmount * 10000;

    if (tokenAmount > remainingSupply) {
        tokenAmount = remainingSupply;
    }

    uint256 usedWeth = tokenAmount / 10000;
    uint256 excessWeth = wethAmount - usedWeth;

    icoFundsWETH += usedWeth;

    bool success = token.mint(msg.sender, tokenAmount);
    require(success, "Token mint failed");

    if (excessWeth > 0) {
        require(weth.transfer(msg.sender, excessWeth), "Refund WETH failed");
    }
}

Mint Function:
function mint(address account, uint256 amount) external onlySwapContract returns (bool) {
require(!icoTokenMinted, "All ICO tokens have been minted!");

_mint(account, amount);
_totalSupply += amount;

if (_totalSupply == ICO_SUPPLY) {
    icoTokenMinted = true;
    swapContract.icoFundsTransfer();
}
emit TokenMinted(amount);

return true;

}
Error Message:ProviderError: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert Allowance exceeded 
I'm encountering this error during minting, and I suspect there may be an issue with how the totalSupply is being updated or how the remaining tokens are calculated. However, I'm struggling to figure out why the totalSupply does not reach the ICO_SUPPLY.
Or maybe there is some problem with a script function which provide swaps:
console.log("Starting swaps...");

for (const user of users) {
  console.log(`Starting swaps for user: ${user.address}`);

  await IWETH.connect(user).deposit({ value: wethAmountToSwap });

  await IWETH.connect(user).approve(TokenSwap, wethAmountToSwap); //maxInt256

  await TokenSwap.connect(user).swapWETHForTokens(wethAmountToSwap);

  const accountMpcBallance = await erc20Contract
    .connect(user)
    .balanceOf(user.address);
  console.log(
    `Account balance is: ${ethers.formatUnits(
      accountMpcBallance.toString()
    )} MPC `
  );

  fs.appendFileSync(
    "swap.txt",
    ` ${user.address} swaped weth to MPC and have : ${ethers.formatUnits(
      accountMpcBallance.toString()
    )} MPC in total \n`
  );
}

when im trying to make a swap until the point where the total supply reaches the limit its like Running on network: ganache Total supply:  0.0 and then i start swaps
Running on network: ganache
Starting swaps...
User balance: 9256.274273362970062838 ETH
Estimated gas cost: 0.0003 ETH
Account WETH balance is: 0.0 WETH
Starting swaps for user: 0x3AF6360128491668e523F6c612806DC62FCDE850
Initial ICO Token Minted Status: false
Is Pool Was Created Status: false
Deposit transaction: {
  value: 50000000000000000000n,
  gasLimit: 300000,
  gasPrice: '1000000000'
}
Account balance is: 500000.0 MPC` for all account same, then when its come nearly to point where totalSupply will reach ICO_SUPPLY its like `Running on network: ganache
Starting swaps...
User balance: 9065.823023963970062838 ETH
Estimated gas cost: 0.3 ETH
Account WETH balance is: 80.0 WETH
Starting swaps for user: 0x3AF6360128491668e523F6c612806DC62FCDE850
Initial ICO Token Minted Status: false
Is Pool Was Created Status: false
Deposit transaction: {
  value: 10000000000000000000n,
  gasLimit: 3000000,
  gasPrice: '1000000000000'
}
ProviderError: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert Allowance exceeded

function which i use to providing swaps
const wethAmountToSwap = ethers.parseEther("10", 18);
  // const wethAmountToSwapInWei = ethers.parseEther(wethAmountToSwap.toString());

  try {
    await executeSwaps();
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }

  async function executeSwaps() {
    console.log("Starting swaps...");
    const gasPrice = ethers.parseUnits("1000", "gwei");

    for (const user of users) {
      const userBalance = await ethers.provider.getBalance(user.address);
      console.log(`User balance: ${ethers.formatEther(userBalance)} ETH`);

      const estimatedGasCost = gasPrice * BigInt(300000);
      console.log(
        `Estimated gas cost: ${ethers.formatEther(estimatedGasCost)} ETH`
      );

      const accountWethBallance = await IWETH.connect(user).balanceOf(
        user.address
      );
      console.log(
        `Account WETH balance is: ${ethers.formatUnits(
          accountWethBallance.toString()
        )} WETH`
      );

      if (userBalance < estimatedGasCost + wethAmountToSwap) {
        console.log(`Insufficient funds for user: ${user.address}`);
        continue;
      }

      console.log(`Starting swaps for user: ${user.address}`);
      console.log("Initial ICO Token Minted Status:", icoTokenMinted);
      console.log("Is Pool Was Created Status:", isPoolWasCreated);

      console.log("Deposit transaction:", {
        value: wethAmountToSwap,
        gasLimit: 3000000,
        gasPrice: gasPrice.toString(),
      });

      await IWETH.connect(user).deposit({
        value: wethAmountToSwap,
        gasLimit: 3000000,
        gasPrice: gasPrice,
      });

      await IWETH.connect(user).approve(TokenSwap, wethAmountToSwap, {
        gasLimit: 3000000,
        gasPrice: gasPrice,
      }); //maxInt256

      await TokenSwap.connect(user).swapWETHForTokens(wethAmountToSwap, {
        gasLimit: 5000000,
        gasPrice: gasPrice,
      });

      const accountMpcBallance = await erc20Contract
        .connect(user)
        .balanceOf(user.address);
      console.log(
        `Account balance is: ${ethers.formatUnits(
          accountMpcBallance.toString()
        )} MPC `
      );

      fs.appendFileSync(
        "swap.txt",
        ` ${user.address} swaped weth to MPC and have : ${ethers.formatUnits(
          accountMpcBallance.toString()
        )} MPC in total \n`
      );
    }
  }


Start by checking the code that generates the error "Allowance exceeded". None of the functions provided generates that error.

The issue is that I have a minting limit for the ICO, and up until the point where the total supply reaches the limit, all calls are successful. During this process, I check the account balances, and the tokens are present. However, when the key swap is supposed to trigger the minting of the final tokens, it returns the error: "revert Allowance exceeded". If I decrease the wethToSwap value, the swaps proceed, and the token amount gradually approaches the designated limit. But when it comes time to reach the maximum, it always throws this error.

Without the code that generates the error "Allowance exceeded" there's no way to diagnose the bug. The functions you provided have several reverts but none of them generate that message.
